# js nest try in catch block

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, try-catch

I have a promise that awaits promises (getCookie). if getCookie('key') is rejected I try to get the key from another cookie (scope). I thought of it like this:

```
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {   
         var key, scope;  
         try {
             key = await getCookie('key');
             resolve(key)
         }
         catch(err){
             try {
                 scope = await getCookie('scope');
                 key = getKeyFromScope(scope);
                 resolve(key)
             } catch(err) {
                 reject(err);
             }
         }
    }
```

However, nesting is only allowed within the try block. Is there a better way to write it with try/catch?

Comment: *"nesting is only allowed within the try block"* – what do you base this statement on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better (simpler) way to write it without try-catch at all. And without the async/await stuff that also revolves around Promises. Only using the Promises themselves.

```
var yourPromise = getCookie('key').catch(() => getCookie('scope').then(getKeyFromScope));
```

`yourPromise` resolves either to the `key`, or to the error thrown by `getCookie('scope')`